# Dependencies Don't Update Automatically in Akka Project

Tags: eclipse, sbt

So I have Juno, with Scala IDE installed, and I have a project that was generated with Activator.

The project has a build.sbt file. I went and added two hamcrest projects and sbt sees them and runs the tests no problem.

I fiddled for some time with eclipse, which refused to see the files. I have m2eclipse installed. I did a clean. Nothing.

Eventually, I just went to sbt and regenerated the eclipse project file. That worked. Question: is this how this is supposed to work? is this how people are working with sbt projects in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this is indeed the case: you have to remake the project files.

I have since moved on to using IntelliJ. They claim Play2 support, but it also requires remaking the project files, which, in 2013, is pretty ludicrous.